# $(x)f=y$ is more natural than $y=f(x)$

Tags: soft-question, notation

Has anyone ever considered the notation such as $(x)f=y$ that specifies the argument $x$ of the function first and then the function itself? I have never seen anyone use it but it seems more natural and logical. For instance $(x)fg=y$ would imply that $f$ is applied first and $g$ second. I am interested in the history behind the standard notation. When was it used first and why the unnatural order was preferred?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but people do use this notation quite often. For instance, lots of papers and books on group theory use $xf$ and sometimes $x^f$ instead of $f(x)$, and define composition $fg$ as applying first $f$ and then $g$.

Comment: I actually think they way that we write things is the natural order. For the reason that $fg(x)$ goes along with the idea of working from the inside out. As we already do when we do arithmetic.

Comment: In terms of unconventional ordering of mathematical notation, you might take a look at Polish and reverse Polish notation.

Comment: @TheNumber23 Note that $((x)g)f$ also goes along with the idea of working from the inside out, only in this case "inside" is left and "outside" is right.

Comment: When I read I usually like to start at the beginning and finish at the end. For me, the beginning is the argument $x$, so I'd rather start with that and gradually work my way to the value $y$.

Comment: For example, Herstein "Topics in Algebra" usually (but not consistently) writes mappings on the right: $xT$ rather than $Tx$.  He remarks "As a general rule, algebraists write mappings on the right, other mathematicians writing them on the left."

Comment: You seem to think one of the choices is natural and the other unnatural. This is very strange.

Comment: One could just as well feel that the function is the one ‘solid’ thing here, the argument and value being incidental ephemera. This doesn’t make one feeling more natural than the other.

Comment: @Andrew: It seems to me that Andrey’s view, as expressed in his *beginning to end* comment, leads ineluctably to RPN (which I don’t much enjoy reading but *very* strongly prefer for calculators.)

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: I wasn't thinking about binary operators, just functions.

Comment: @Andrey: But every binary operation **is** a function.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: well, in programming a binary operation is different from a function. In any case, if you're asking me whether I prefer $(3,4)+$ to $3+4$, I prefer the latter.

Comment: The origins of mathematical notation, at least of the denotation of numbers, lie in Arabic which is read from right to left. So there's no reason at all why you can't read equations that way. You have to get used to saying "y taken from x" instead of "x minus y", "the cube of x" instead of "x cubed", and so on. And it may help to use the old-fashioned "three-and-twenty", too.

Comment: Function notation is much later and comes from left-to-right Europeans, who said "the sine of angle x", shortened it to "$\sin x$", and then generalised to $f(x)$.